# Make a Condition with If Contain Number Via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My `msg.text` = `/start 76198769`
**/start + space + 76198769**

How Can I Make a Condition if `msg.text` = /start+76198769 then Temp = 76198769 ?

I Mean, I want to get `76198769`

```
await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `telegram.me/myBot?start=${msg.chat.id}`, opts);
```

Comment: Fix your syntax first please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few ways to do it.  Simplest is to probably just split your string.

```
let vals = msg.text.split(' '); // yields an array of '/start', '76198769'
let temp = null;
if(vals[0] === '/start' && vals[1] === '76198769') { 
  temp = parseInt(vals[1]);
}
```

Or with Regex, you could do

```
let matches = /\/start\s(\d+)/g.exec(msg.text);
let temp = null;
if(matches.length) {
  temp = parseInt(matches[1]);
}
```

Just for fun, I'd point out that what I'm recommending here could be extended as well.   For example, if you have a list of commands you want to use, you could test for them and then route the command to some other code.

Let's say you have commands like 'start', 'stop', 'info'.  If you create an object (perhaps through requires in Node) like this:

```
const commands = {
  'start' : function(args) { /* handle start */},
  'stop' : function(args) { /* handle stop */},
  'info' : function(args) { /* handle info */}
};
```

You can construct your regex and fetch it like this:

```
const regex = /\/(start|stop|info)\s(\d+)/g;
let command = null;
let args = null;
let matches = regex.exec(msg.text);
if(matches.length) {
  command = matches[1];
  args = parseInt(matches[2]);
}
```

Then you can execute your command with `commands[command](args);`

If you really want, you can even construct your regex from a string by concatenating the keys of the commands object, but I'll leave that as an exercise to you. :)

Comment: vals[1] is a variable number, if that number change, Will the code work?

Comment: If vals[1] can be any number at all, then just remove the second condition in the if, to make it `if(vals[0] === '/start') {... }`.

Comment: First one is ok But with regex , I'm Using ```            let matches = msg.text.match(/\/start\s(\d+)/g);
            let temp = null;
            if(matches.length) {
              temp = parseInt(matches[0]);
            }
            console.log(temp);``` But I Got `NaN

Answer (score 3):

Use Regex:

```
var matches = msg.text.match(/(\d+)/g);
if (matches.length > 0) {
    var Temp = parseInt(matches[0]);
}
```

[Example here](https://regex101.com/r/w45CXw/1).

Comment: That's going to match a lot more than he wants, potentially. Also it makes Temp a string, and his example was a number.

Comment: @Paul The example he gave has nothing to suggest there would be other numbers in the same string. But if that's the case, you can easily modify the regex accordingly.

Comment: I agree with Paul, your awnser worked but Paul Awnser is better because your awnser will work with `/anothercommand anyNumber`, I awsered too I prefer my awnser because is more fit and just work with `/start number` , forexample not show error NaN in `/start aaaaa` or when we have olny `/start`, that just work when we have /start and after that only a numbers. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use split()...

```
const temp = msg.text === '/start 76198769' ? msg.text.split(' ')[1] : '';
```

or with regx:

```
var matches = msg.text.match(/\d+/g), temp;
temp = matches.length ? matches[0] : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

**This work Very Good**
Just This work with /start and Numbers

```
    let vals = msg.text.split(' '); 
    let temp = null;
    if (vals[0] === '/start' && Math.round(vals[1])) {
        temp = parseInt(vals[1]);
        console.log(temp); 
    }
```

Comment: This code won't even execute without errors; you're re-assigning a `let` constant for starters, and rounding a string for no reason, then parsing it (again, since the round function parses it as well).